# Comprehensive guide on testing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Is there any comprehensive guides on testing rails apps. Im searching for guide that will tell me what should I test and how should I test it especially with Rspec. Lots of examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec). Sumner does a great job of walking you through writing tests for an entire app. The Hartl book is also a great resource.

Comment: Cool! I'll definitely buy this book

Answer (score 6):

[The RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)

Testing the rails app is part of development so I'd sugest to read [Ruby on Rails Tutorial, Learn Rails by Example by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), it has good explained testing process.

Answer (score 3):

The Rails Guide [A Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) is a good place to start.

It covers the default `test/unit` style of testing.

As suggested by @megas, [the RSpec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) is another place to look.

[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) is a great first book for any rails developer, covering the full process of building an application, testing it as you go.

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at Railscast as well.

Some episodes that talks about testing:

[Episode 275: How I Test](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test)

[Episode 257: Request Specs and Capybara](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara)

[Episode 158: Factories not Fixtures revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures-revised) or [Older Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures)

[Episode 261: Testing JavaScript with Jasmine](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine)